# No Box for Username and Password in TortoiseSVN with Google Code

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-code, svn-checkout

When i check out a Google Code repository I don't get asked for a password or a username.

this is how i try it:

```
https://MyRepository.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

I can't add something like `--username Me@gmail.com` as in comandline.

Any ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are only prompted for a password when committing changes to Google Code.